# React: How ReactToPrint can print dynamic width fit on any page size

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, printing

I have 2 divs contain highchart components, and they are wrapped in each grid separately. I have put a reference on the second div for ReactToPrint to print this div only.

When I maximize the browser, the print preview shows the image cannot fully fit in (refer to below Max window image) . However, when I reduce the browser size, the print preview shows a wide left margin (refer to below Narrow window image).

How can I print that div with **full width** regardless the size of browser on **any page size** e.g. A4 size, A3 size, etc?

**Codes:**

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import ReactToPrint from 'react-to-print';
import HighChartTemp from './HighChartTemp';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import PrintIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Print';

function PrintTest() {

    const printRef = useRef();

    return (
        <div>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                    <Box borderRadius={16} boxShadow={3} >
                        <div><HighChartTemp type='bar' />
                        </div>
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                    <Box borderRadius={16} boxShadow={3} >
                        <div id="page" ref={printRef}>
                            <HighChartTemp type='column' />  {/* print this chart only */}
                            
                        </div>
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Button>
                <ReactToPrint
                    trigger={() => <PrintIcon fontSize="large" style={{ color: 'blue' }} />}
                    content={() => printRef.current}
                    pageStyle="@page { margin-top: 100px;  } "
                />
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PrintTest
```

**Prior to print**
[image: Prior Printing]

**Max window:**
[image: Max window]

**Narrow window:**
[image: Narrow window]

Comment: did you solved it ?

Comment: i still haven't figured out how to dynamically print the chart, but i use the other component react-to-print-advanced to delay printing for seconds. 

I add an option for user to select the paper size for printing. I hide the chart and set the size according to the input then print the chart. That's a delay option in react-to-print-advanced to delay before printing.